# How to install Debian Jessie package in Bullseye in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, debian, tomcat7, debian-jessie

I am trying to install `libtomcat7-java` in my Debian Bullseye Docker container. The problem is that it is only available in the Debian Archives for Jessie.
I tried the follow code:

```
FROM openjdk:8u312-bullseye
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie contrib main non-free\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libtomcat7-java -y
```

However it failed with the message:

```
GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1  
The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release' is not signed.
```

I also tried to install the missing public keys with:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553 7638D0442B90D010 CBF8D6FD518E17E1
```

However it also failed with the message:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553 7638D0442B90D010 CBF8D6FD518E17E1:
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.NOIEOw8ziX/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553 7638D0442B90D010 CBF8D6FD518E17E1
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

How can I install this package from the Debian archives or some other source?

Comment: You can't use libtomcat8-java?

Comment: @HansKilian No, I am trying to migrate the CI pipeline of an old project and it doesn't compile with 8 or 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your Dockerfile the line to import the required keys

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8u312-bullseye
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie contrib main non-free\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install libtomcat7-java -y
```

Build

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/5 : FROM openjdk:8u312-bullseye
 ---> 3bc5f7759e81
Step 2/5 : RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie contrib main non-free\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7480c19230b5
Step 3/5 : RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010
 ---> Running in ac677006b426
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.IPXyQ9cVUQ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010
gpg: key 7638D0442B90D010: public key "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Removing intermediate container ac677006b426
 ---> d0b97edae233
Step 4/5 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 41493ab60868
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [44.1 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [39.4 kB]
Ign:4 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release.gpg [2420 B]
Get:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages [115 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8183 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [2596 B]
Get:10 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie/non-free Sources [99.2 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie/contrib Sources [50.4 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie/main Sources [7063 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie/contrib amd64 Packages [49.8 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages [6818 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie/non-free amd64 Packages [83.2 kB]
Fetched 22.8 MB in 6s (3754 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Removing intermediate container 41493ab60868
 ---> c0f07a3f6af9
Step 5/5 : RUN apt-get install libtomcat7-java -y
 ---> Running in 20c3dd999c50
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-pool-java libecj-java libservlet3.0-java
Suggested packages:
  libcommons-dbcp-java-doc libgeronimo-jta-1.2-spec-java ant ecj tomcat7
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-pool-java libecj-java libservlet3.0-java
  libtomcat7-java
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 5997 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7016 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libcommons-pool-java all 1.6-4 [109 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libcommons-dbcp-java all 1.4-7 [157 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libecj-java all 3.16.0-1 [1781 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie/main amd64 libservlet3.0-java all 7.0.56-3+deb8u11 [317 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie/main amd64 libtomcat7-java all 7.0.56-3+deb8u11 [3634 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 5997 kB in 0s (12.5 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libcommons-pool-java.
(Reading database ... 12672 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcommons-pool-java_1.6-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcommons-pool-java (1.6-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcommons-dbcp-java.
Preparing to unpack .../libcommons-dbcp-java_1.4-7_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcommons-dbcp-java (1.4-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libecj-java.
Preparing to unpack .../libecj-java_3.16.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libecj-java (3.16.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libservlet3.0-java.
Preparing to unpack .../libservlet3.0-java_7.0.56-3+deb8u11_all.deb ...
Unpacking libservlet3.0-java (7.0.56-3+deb8u11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtomcat7-java.
Preparing to unpack .../libtomcat7-java_7.0.56-3+deb8u11_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtomcat7-java (7.0.56-3+deb8u11) ...
Setting up libservlet3.0-java (7.0.56-3+deb8u11) ...
Setting up libecj-java (3.16.0-1) ...
Setting up libcommons-pool-java (1.6-4) ...
Setting up libcommons-dbcp-java (1.4-7) ...
Setting up libtomcat7-java (7.0.56-3+deb8u11) ...
Removing intermediate container 20c3dd999c50
 ---> c1fdb38567a1
Successfully built c1fdb38567a1
```